# Count hidden next-line items in a list

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list with inline list-items. I can see about 8 but then there is not enough space to show more and the rest appears on the next line, hidden (behind the container's z-index) because of its `overflow:hidden`. How can I count these next line items with JavaScript?

I know jQuery has `$('li:visible')` but I need a vanilla JavaScript way.

I've tried to leverage `getComputedStyle(el)` but there doesn't seem to be any way to target these hidden items.

There is also a complicated [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) but I don't think it can be used for elements, only the document visibility.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/pwej1v32/) of the list items

Answer (score 2):

For your situation, you need to id if the top of the LI is "under the fold" of the UL. For this we can use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
function isVis(elm){
 var box = elm.getBoundingClientRect(), 
 par = elm.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
 return par.bottom-par.top>= box.top;
}
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ntcsh18g/

note this is NOT a general purpose "is the element hidden" routine, which is complicated and slow, rather its a simple check against the OP's property that's causing "hiddennes"...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As suggested by @dandavis, my solution was not generic at all (only works for one row of elements), so only use this in extremely specific and simple cases! To generalize this approach you could try and check whether the `offsetTop` of an element is greater than the height of the container or the `offsetLeft` is bigger than the width. Anyway, you are probably better off using his solution anyway. ;)

---

Well, depending on what you need this for, a very ugly, but working solution could be to check for elements that have a different `offsetTop` than the first element like this:

```
const children = [...document.querySelectorAll('#container li')]
const normalOffset = children[0].offsetTop
const overflownChildren = children.filter(li => li.offsetTop !== normalOffset)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Isti115/nc3tahw3/

Comment: an issue with `offsetTop` is padding and borders (depending on the box model of course). also the code shown only determines "first row?", not "is hidden?"; if there were more than one row of "icons" shown, this would not equate...

Comment: Yes, you're right, but if the only need is to distinguish between the not overflown and the overflown element fro one row, then this difference could be enough. :) Anyway, your solution seems to be nicer (I haven't heard about `getBoundingClientRect` before), so I'll upvote that and learn it for next time!

Comment: in a perfect world, your simple property check would work as well as my ugly function call. js aint that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to target the ul element and save that into a variable `var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");` Then use for-loop something like below

```
<ul id="foo">
 <li>First</li>
 <li>Second</li>
 <li>Third</li>
</ul>


var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i) {
// filter so that only lists with the class "foo" are counted
 if (/(^|\\s)foo(\\s|$)/.test(lists[i].className)) {
    var items = lists[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; ++j) {
        // do something with items[j]
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: aside: `lists[i].classList.contains("foo")` works everywhere these days.